# Why isn't the quotient space $X=\mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})$ first-countable?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the quotient space $X=\mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})$ I'm supposed to prove it isn't first countable. It seems to me that this space is homeomorphic to two open triangles joined at their apexes with that point added. That point is the problematic one, but why isn't the collection of open balls with descending rational radii centered at this point intersected with $X$ a countable basis?

Thank you for your answers.

Edit: I found this problem on my university's website. We did this same problem at school but first-countability was replaced with local compactness. It could be possible that the space is in fact first-countable, and the problem statement on the website was incorrect.

Comment: Consider the neighbourhood $\{(x, y)\in \Bbb R^2\mid -e^{-x^2}<y<e^{-x^2}\}$ of the problematic point. That's not contained in any of your rational-radius neighbourhoods. So that's a counter to your one example. Haven't figured out a general proof, though.

Comment: Maybe we can use diagonalization? Observe your statement is equivalent to: 
There doesn't exist a countable collection of open sets $\{U_n\}$ such that for every open set $U$ containing $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$, $\mathbb R\times \{0\}\subset U_n\subset U$ for some $n$.

Comment: @Arthur, I thought it was the other way around, i. e. that any open set containing the point has to contain a basis element?

Comment: @InsertNameHere You're right. I didn't keep my phrasing straight. Still, my point stands: that set is a witness that your proposed basis isn't actually a basis.

Comment: What is the equivalence relation being used to get the quotient space?

Comment: @Nemo Collapsing $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$ to a point.

Comment: @YuiToCheng i.e. $(x_1,y_1) \sim (x_2,y_2) ~:\Longleftrightarrow~ y_1 = y_2$ ?

Comment: @Nemo It's $x\sim y$ for $x,y\in \mathbb R \times \{0\}$ and nothing else is equivalent to others besides itself.

Comment: @YuiToCheng ohhh! Ok. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ is collapsed to a point $\ast \in X=\mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{R} \times \{0\})$. This point does not have a  countable base of open neighborhoods.

$X$ is endowed with the quotient topology. This means that open neigborhoods of $\ast$ are in a $1$-$1$-correspondence with open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$. Let us denote the collection of these sets by $\mathfrak{U}$.

Therefore, as YuiTo Cheng remarked in his comments, we have to show that there does not exist a countable collection of sets $U_ n \in \mathfrak{U}$ such that for every $U \in \mathfrak{U}$, $U_n  \subset U$  for some $n$.

Let us consider any countable collection of $U_ n \in \mathfrak{U}$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a number $u_n > 0$ such that $(n,u_n) \in U_n$. The set $D = \{(n,u_n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, thus $U = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus D \in \mathfrak{U}$. But by construction no $U_n$ can be contained in $U$.

Remark:

This generalizes as follows. Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces such that $X$ contains an infinite subset $A \subset X$ without limit points and let $y \in Y$ be a point such that $\{ y \}$ is not open in $Y$. Then $(X \times Y)/(X \times \{ y \})$ is not first countable.